# localStorage writeln multiple values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a function to save values on a few pages.

If I try to return them on another page and writeln them it works. But it gives out the first value 1 time, the second value 2 times, the third value 3 times and so on.
I can't figure out where the problem is.

```
let aus = "";
let h1 = localStorage.getItem("h1");
   
for (i=0; i<localStorage.length; i++)  {  
  key = localStorage.key(i);  
  let v = localStorage.getItem(key);
  window.document.writeln(aus +=  "<div id='favInfo'><a href='" + v + "' target='blank'>" + localStorage.key(i) +"</a></div>")
  console.log(localStorage);
}
```

Comment: Does it work without the aus variable?

Comment: Never use `document.write` or `document.writeln`. They are from an age of JS that died decades ago, and are an incredible anti-pattern. Add your content using normal modern JS, either through `innerHTML` or by using normal DOM functions (createElement, appendChild, etc). Also, don't assign-update a variable when using it as function parameter. And if you're going the string composition route (e.g. `innerHTML` with string + string + string + ...) don't use the `+` operator, use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).